# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' - after deploying my react redux application using Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux, react-redux

I recently used Google's Firebase to deploy my application. But somehow something is going wrong. Please access the below link to view the exact error trace.

In my build, everything looks normal all the CSS files and JS files have the appropriate code but after the deployment all the Files have HTML, go through the Below URL and watch the console to have a better idea of the error.

https://workout-wfh.web.app/

View both Images to view the difference : 
1. [In the deployed application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtOdA.png)

2. [In my local build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwFGI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you view the source of the deployed website, you'll see that the `<script>` tag is trying to load this URL:

https://workout-wfh.web.app/MohanVarma1965/workout.git/static/js/main.5cca3537.chunk.js

which doesn't exist and so is falling back to your default HTML content. It looks like your build process is generating absolute URLs that include your username and directory path. You should adjust your build tooling to leave out everything before `/js`.

Comment: Thank you so much I have changed my package.json to have this 
"homepage": "./", which added the relative path. Previously I had a project URL for the Homepage which caused the issue. It work's now Thanks a lot @Michael Bleigh.